# Access GUI from my applicaton layer (Layered System)

Tags: java, swing

Say in my main method I call my appLayer and GUI as below:

```
    ApplicationLayer appLayer = new ApplicationLayer(dataLayer);
    GUI gui = new GUI(appLayer);
```

Within my GUI I have buttons then when clicked, call the appLayer and then do the logic with the data layer (Not shown above).

Once I have the data, I want to access the GUI again to update fields with the data I have gathered. Is there an easy way to do so from the application layer, or do I have to pass the data to the GUI and update from there.

Hopefully this is clear!

Comment: Events - Observer pattern to the rescue !

Comment: Some observer pattern examples are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).